# Is this question ridiculous?

Tags: discussion

[How should we call a book with New Testament and Psalms?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25963/can-we-call-the-new-testament-with-psalm-a-bible)

It got closed as "unclear what you are asking" and there are three downvotes. This made me assume that the question is ridiculous.

Is this really a ridiculous question? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

"Can we really call this a Bible"

That statement by itself is the reason I closed the question.

Also, what *exactly* are you trying to learn with that question?

Answer (score 2):

I thought it a fine question, but I suppose some people may have considered it a "truth" question. It is definitely on the border thereof.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is fine. If you edit to "Why do they do this?" It will probably be reopened. Affable gave pretty close to the answer I would have.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good question and if you know what the origin of bible is from the greek many things can be called that.